# Writing an Excel table to Excel using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am using Excel Interop to generate Excel Table into an xlsx file. I have a very simple table with 3 columns and no header, no totals but has 2 rows.
Now when I generate the Excel file, I use the following code

```
...
Range rng = worksheet.Range["$A$1:$C$2"];
ListObject lo = worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, Type.Missing, XlYesNoGuess.xlNo);
lo.ShowHeaders = false;
...
```

With the above code it generates the table with cell range A2:C3 instead of A1:C2. But any values I set in the A row are set but outside of the table.
If I set the ShowHeaders to true in the 3rd line of code above, then Excel is converting the top row as the header line and still moves the table cell range to A2:C3

Am I doing something wrong? I appreciate any and all help and guidance to fix this issue.

Thanks

Jaideep

Comment: ONly as a suggestion: Use a library like EPPLUS. It is free of charge and way faster / easier than the Interop stuff.

Comment: @ChristianSauer: Faster I agree but easier? Can you explain that for me? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout It is easier because the EPPLUS library is a lot more the ".NET-way" than the interop stuff. For example EPPlus supports linq queries, uses lists instead of arrays and has a ton of useful methods like "create a new sheet from this datatable". Also, Interop has accumulated so much weird stuff over the years that it is very hard to understand - epplus looks a lot more discoverable.

Comment: @ChristianSauer: Ummm, I will have to respectfully disagree with you there. And the reason is very simple. For a guy who has been using VB all his life will find `vb.net` easier than `C#` and `vice-versa`. Similarly, a guy who has a good VBA background will always find Interop much more easier than automating excel via EPPLUS or OpenXML etc. No doubt I would prefer using EPPLUS to automate Excel from VS but saying that it is easier than Interop really doesn't do justice. It all depends on what are you comfortable with. CONTD...

Comment: @ChristianSauer CONTD... Regarding `Interop has accumulated so much weird stuff over the years that it is very hard to understand`, If you have a VBA background then again it would would be easier for you to find the .Net equivalent :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am a VBA guy of sorts - but I don't like VBA for a lot of reasons, but most of them could be boiled down to "vba is simply old, and doesn't support thins I take for granted in languages [be it VB.NET C# or Java]". 
I think it ok to use Interop when you are deeply invested in VBA, but it is still awfully slow compared to using Office Open XML or EPPlus directly.

Comment: @ChristianSauer: I never disputed the fact about `Interop` being slow :) My first comment supports what you mentioned. In fact in my later comments as well I recommend using `EEPLUS` over `INTEROP`.  I am discussing the "Being Easier" part of it which is not right... rather the definition of "Being Easier" will change from individual to individual... And that is my point :)

Comment: @ChristianSauer One of the reason I am, currently, stuck with Interop is we have to support the old xls - non Open XML standard to boht read and write values and formulas.

Comment: @SiddharthRout On that fact we agree ;) Easier mostly depends on the person.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//
//~~> Rest of your code
//

Range rng = worksheet.Range["$A$1:$C$2"];
ListObject lo = worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, Type.Missing, XlYesNoGuess.xlNo);
lo.ShowHeaders = false;
Excel.Range rngRowOne = worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
rngRowOne.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);

//
//~~> Rest of your code
//
```